# Migration failed with source plugin exception: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: 7, migrations

I'm trying to migrate user's content profiles (Drupal 6) to Profile2's profiles (Drupal 7) using the example from http://grasmash.com/article/migrate-classes-content-profile-profile2. When I try importing, I get the following error:

> Migration failed with source plugin exception: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ctp.field_titul_pred_jmenem' in 'field list'

This is the migration class.

```
class SkipProfile2Migration extends Migration {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->description = t('Migration of content profile into profile2 entities');

    $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
      array(
        'nid' => array(
          'type' => 'int',
          'unsigned' => TRUE,
          'not null' => TRUE,
          'description' => 'D6 Unique Node ID',
          'alias' => 'n',
        )
      ),
      MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema(),
        'default'
    );
    $query = Database::getConnection('default', 'legacy')
      ->select('node', 'n')
      ->fields('n', array('nid', 'vid', 'type', 'language', 'title', 'uid', 'status', 'created', 'changed', 'comment', 'promote', 'moderate', 'sticky', 'tnid', 'translate'))
      ->condition('n.type', 'profile', '=');
    $query->join('skip' . '.node_revisions', 'nr', 'n.vid = nr.vid');
    $query->addField('nr', 'body');
    $query->addField('nr', 'teaser');
    $query->addField('nr', 'format');
    $query->join('skip' . '.users', 'u', 'n.uid = u.uid');
    $query->addField('u', 'name');
    $query->leftJoin('skip' . '.content_type_clovek', 'ctp', 'n.nid = ctp.nid AND n.vid = ctp.vid');
    $query->addField('ctp','field_titul_pred_jmenem');
    $query->addField('ctp','field_krestni_jmeno');
    $query->addField('ctp','field_prijmeni');
    $query->addField('ctp','field_titul_za_jmenem');
    $query->addField('ctp','field_telefon');
    $query->addField('ctp','field_email_source');
    $query->addField('ctp','field_ulice');
    $query->addField('ctp','field_cislo_popisne');
    $query->addField('ctp','field_sidlo');
    $query->addField('ctp','field_smerovaci_cislo');
    $query->addField('ctp','field_funkce_cloveka');
    $query->addField('ctp','field_pracoviste');
    $query->addField('ctp','field_stat_iso');
    $query->orderBy('n.nid', 'ASC');

    $source_fields = array(
      'nid' => t('The node ID of the page'),
      'uid' => t('The user ID of a user'),
      'lid' => t('The location ID of a location instance'),
    );

    // Create a MigrateSource object, which manages retrieving the input data.
    $this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query, $source_fields);
    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationProfile2('clovek');

// FIELD MAPPINGS    ...
```

Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: Looks like there's no column called `field_titul_pred_jmenem` in the `content_type_clovek ` table. Wouldn't it be something like `field_titul_pred_jmenem_value` instead?

Comment: As side note, there isn't the need to write `'skip' . '.users'`; just write `'skip.users'`. (There is no need to concatenate two literal strings.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Drupal 6 running CCK, the database field names are different from the CCK field names.

In my test site running Drupal 6, I created the following CCK fields:

- field_code_page (text)
- field_co_author (user reference)
- field_book_list (node reference)

  [image: screenshot]

The database table created from CCK for the content type containing those fields has the following database fields:

- field_code_page_value
- field_co_author_uid
- field_book_list_nid

  [image: screenshot]

It is rather probable the database field is named ctp.field_titul_pred_jmenem_value. To be sure, you should check the database table, as the database field could have a different name, basing on the type of the CCK field.

Comment: Thanks, migration ended up "successfully", but no items were processed. The interesting thing is, that "content_type_clovek" database table didn't have fields like "field_titul_pred_jmenem_value", so I had to create them manually. I have no idea where to proceed from here...

Comment: If that database field was not present, you should not have used `$query->addField('ctp','field_titul_pred_jmenem')` in the migration SQL query. Probably, there aren't nodes of that content type with a value for that CCK field.

Comment: There are nodes with a value for that CCK field, so there must be another reason. So it seems, that my database is different from http://grasmash.com/article/migrate-classes-content-profile-profile2, where I borrowed the code. Strange.

Comment: I discovered, that I had a problem in original code, so when I corrected it to `->condition('n.type', 'profile', '=');`, it imported everything quite nicely. The problem is, that fields from content profile aren't mapped, so it's rather useless discovery (and yes, I also corrected my field mappings and checked them through Migrate UI). How can I debug this further?